# Check if nested arrays in object contains empty values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following object:

```
{
  "params": {
    "time_to_diagnosis": [
      {
        "field": "date_of_diagnosis",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "field": "date_of_symptom_onset",
        "value": "2019-09-01"
      }
    ],
    "time_since_onset": [
      {
        "field": "date_of_symptom_onset",
        "value": "2019-09-01"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can tell this is a object , of objects with arrays that them selves contains objects.

As you can see some keys are empty.

The idea is that if there are no empty keys in the arrays containing objects, then return true, else return false.

Heres what I wrote:

```
const isParamsInAjaxParamsEmpty = (paramsForAjaxCall) => {
  for (const key in paramsForAjaxCall) {
    for (const nestedKey in paramsForAjaxCall[key]) {
      const params = paramsForAjaxCall[key];

      if (params[nestedKey] === "") {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

I Know I can do an `Array.isArray` on the nestedKey part, but Im not sure how to make this recursive, as there could be one or more arrays.

`paramsForAjaxCall` is the object above.

**Thoughts?**

Comment: `isParamsInAjaxParamsEmpty` suggests this is for posting to a server. If a form created this, I would do validation on the form instead. It's much simpler to report an error to the user than this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `map` the array then take the `values` from the `Object` and with `every` will get a `boolean` value so it's an array of booleans in the end because we `mapping`.

if this array  `contains` a `false` so the result is false

```js
const data = {
  "params": {
    "time_to_diagnosis": [{
        "field": "date_of_diagnosis",
        "value": "ddd"
      },
      {
        "field": "date_of_symptom_onset",
        "value": "2019-09-01"
      }
    ],
    "time_since_onset": [{
      "field": "date_of_symptom_onset",
      "value": "2019-09-01"
    }]
  }
}

const res = !Object.values(data).map(o => Object.values(o).map(value => value.every(({
  value
}) => value !== ""))).flat().includes(false)


console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a check for not object and return false, then check for the wanted property or iterate all properties.

```js
function check(object) {
    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return false;
    if (object.value) return true;
    return Object.values(object).every(check);
}

var object = { params: { time_to_diagnosis: [{ field: "date_of_diagnosis", value: "" }, { field: "date_of_symptom_onset", value: "2019-09-01" }], time_since_onset: [{ field: "date_of_symptom_onset", value: "2019-09-01" }] } }

console.log(check(object));

object.params.time_to_diagnosis[0].value= "foo";
console.log(check(object));
```